# How can I get exit code of process when systemd OnFailure is triggered?

Tags: systemd, exit-code

This is the OnFailure config in systemd service file.

[image]

And the content of failure@%n.service file is as below
[image]

Just as above, if the process fails, failure_handler.sh bash file is triggered. But I want to get the exit code of the process in failure_handler.sh. How can I get it?

Answer (score 2):

`systemctl show failed_unit_name |grep ExecMainStatus`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `systemctl show` to get this information:

```bash
systemctl show some.service --property ExecMainStatus
```